# Correct HTML Component with the name must be given correctly

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I getting error Like
Fail 1

> Correct HTML Component with the name
> 'userName/contactNumber/emailId/confirmEmailId/status/submit' must be given correctly

Fail 2

> Correct HTML Component with the name 'userName' must be used with appropriate constraints

How to solve this?

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    
    <body style="background-color: lavender">
        <center>
            <h1>Welcome to Online Help Services</h1>
    
            <form:form action="/register" method="post" modelAttribute="register">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>UserName:</td>
                        <td><form:input path="userName" id="userName" /></td>
                        <td><form:errors path="userName" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Contact Number</td>
                        <td><form:input path="contactNumber" id="contactNumber" /></td>
                        <td><form:errors path="contactNumber" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email Id</td>
                        <td><form:input path="emailId" id="emailId" /></td>
                        <td><form:errors path="emailId" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Confirm Email Id</td>
                        <td><form:input path="confirmEmailId" id="confirmEmailId" /></td>
                        <td><form:errors path="confirmEmailId" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><form:checkbox path="status" id="status" /></td>
                        <td>I agree</td>
                        <td><form:errors path="status" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" /></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Cancel" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form:form>
        </center>
            
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, the error is with your `application.properties` file. Provide the proper prefix and suffix to the spring mvc view.

Comment: This can be given as comment instead of a answer.

Comment: My "add a comment" was disabled that's why I chose this way.